# Google direction API json file parsing

Tags: android, json, mobile, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I used Google direction API and received data as a json file. My url is like

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false

and I used optimized:true parameter. As I read it gives me optimal path from source to destination through the waypoints. And now i dont know structure of json file exactly. I look up the structure of json file but i don t know how can i take order of path that Google direction API gives me.

Comment: You havent marked any questions as answered.  Ever.   Fix that with your old ones and people will be more willing to help you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to understand how to parse it. Use these:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to use the Direction Api of Google in Android.
So I made an open source project to help doing that.
You can find it here:https://github.com/MathiasSeguy-Android2EE/GDirectionsApiUtils

How it works, definitly simply:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements DCACallBack{
/**
 * Get the Google Direction between mDevice location and the touched location using the     Walk
 * @param point
 */
private void getDirections(LatLng point) {
     GDirectionsApiUtils.getDirection(this, mDeviceLatlong, point,     GDirectionsApiUtils.MODE_WALKING);
}

/*
 * The callback
 * When the direction is built from the google server and parsed, this method is called and give you the expected direction
 */
@Override
public void onDirectionLoaded(List<GDirection> directions) {        
    // Display the direction or use the DirectionsApiUtils
    for(GDirection direction:directions) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "onDirectionLoaded : Draw GDirections Called with path " + directions);
        GDirectionsApiUtils.drawGDirection(direction, mMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call which you mentioned will give the optimal route that you should follow. In order to know what the route is you need to see the value for ***waypoint_order***.

For your call, the waypoint order is:
"waypoint_order" : [ 3, 2, 0, 1 ]

So, the optimal result would be that you need to visit the waypoints in the order: Origin - 3 - 2 - 0 - 1 - Destination.

In your case it would be:
*Adelaide,SA - McLaren Vale,SA - Connawarra,SA - Barossa Valley,SA - Clare,SA - Adelaide,SA*

for your call:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false